# Unbalanced Stack Problem

Tags: c#, c++, dll, dllimport

Zhanks for all the help that I receifed on my "c# Problems with repeated console.writeline commands" on Friday. I found out that that all my problems are caused by a: "PInvokeStackImbalance".

- I use C# Express on a WIN7 64 bit
  machine
- The ftcjtag.dll that I call is a 32 bit c++ dll. I have a 64 bit version
  of this dll available.
- This dll can be downloaded at http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/SoftwareExamples/MPSSE/FTCJTAG/FTCJTAG_200.zip
- I just started coding c# and everything that I googled so far is confusing me more than helping me. I hope that you can give me a hint whats wrong with my code or a suggestion what to do.

Error Message:

> PInvokeStackImbalance wurde erkannt.
>   Message: A call to PInvoke function 'WindowsFormsApplication1!WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1::JTAG_GetHiSpeedDeviceNameLocIDChannel' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;




namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        uint ftStatus = FTC_SUCCESS;
        //uint numHiSpeedDevices = 0; // 32-bit unsigned integer
        byte[] byteHiSpeedDeviceName = new byte[MAX_NUM_DEVICE_NAME_CHARS];
        byte[] byteHiSpeedDeviceChannel = new byte[MAX_NUM_CHANNEL_CHARS];
        string hiSpeedChannel = null;

        uint locationID = 0;
        //UInt32 locationID = 0;

        uint hiSpeedDeviceType = 1;
        //UInt32 hiSpeedDeviceType = 1;

        //uint clk_div = 0;
        uint numBytesReturned = 0;
        private enum HI_SPEED_DEVICE_TYPES// : uint
        {
            FT2232H_DEVICE_TYPE = 1,
            FT4232H_DEVICE_TYPE = 2
        };
        string hiSpeedDeviceName = null;
        IntPtr ftHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
        public string bPin2LowHighState { get; set; }

        private const string App_Title = "FT2232/FT4232 JTAG Device C# .NET Test Application";
        private const string Dll_Version_Label = "FT2232/FT4232 JTAG DLL Version = ";
        private const string Device_Name_Label = "Device Name = ";

        private const uint FTC_SUCCESS = 0;
        private const uint FTC_DEVICE_IN_USE = 27;
        private const uint TEST_LOGIC_STATE = 1;
        private const uint RUN_TEST_IDLE_STATE = 2;
        private const uint MAX_NUM_DEVICE_NAME_CHARS = 100;
        private const uint MAX_NUM_CHANNEL_CHARS = 5;
        private const uint MAX_NUM_DLL_VERSION_CHARS = 10;
        private const uint MAX_NUM_ERROR_MESSAGE_CHARS = 100;
        private const uint WRITE_DATA_BUFFER_SIZE = 65536;
        private const uint READ_DATA_BUFFER_SIZE = 65536;
        private const uint READ_CMDS_DATA_BUFFER_SIZE = 131071;

        byte[] WriteDataBuffer = new byte[WRITE_DATA_BUFFER_SIZE];
        byte[] ReadDataBuffer = new byte[READ_DATA_BUFFER_SIZE];

        public uint clockFrequencyHz = 0;

        FTC_INPUT_OUTPUT_PINS LowInputOutputPinsData;
        FTH_INPUT_OUTPUT_PINS HighInputOutputPinsData;
        FTC_LOW_HIGH_PINS LowPinsInputData;
        FTH_LOW_HIGH_PINS HighPinsInputData;

        //**************************************************************************
        // TYPE DEFINITIONS
        //**************************************************************************

        public struct FTC_INPUT_OUTPUT_PINS
        {
            public bool bPin1InputOutputState;
            public bool bPin1LowHighState;
            public bool bPin2InputOutputState;
            public bool bPin2LowHighState;
            public bool bPin3InputOutputState;
            public bool bPin3LowHighState;
            public bool bPin4InputOutputState;
            public bool bPin4LowHighState;
        }
        public struct FTH_INPUT_OUTPUT_PINS
        {
            public bool bPin1InputOutputState;
            public bool bPin1LowHighState;
            public bool bPin2InputOutputState;
            public bool bPin2LowHighState;
            public bool bPin3InputOutputState;
            public bool bPin3LowHighState;
            public bool bPin4InputOutputState;
            public bool bPin4LowHighState;
            public bool bPin5InputOutputState;
            public bool bPin5LowHighState;
            public bool bPin6InputOutputState;
            public bool bPin6LowHighState;
            public bool bPin7InputOutputState;
            public bool bPin7LowHighState;
            public bool bPin8InputOutputState;
            public bool bPin8LowHighState;
        }
        public struct FTC_LOW_HIGH_PINS
        {
            public bool bPin1LowHighState;
            public bool bPin2LowHighState;
            public bool bPin3LowHighState;
            public bool bPin4LowHighState;
        }
        public struct FTH_LOW_HIGH_PINS
        {
            public bool bPin1LowHighState;
            public bool bPin2LowHighState;
            public bool bPin3LowHighState;
            public bool bPin4LowHighState;
            public bool bPin5LowHighState;
            public bool bPin6LowHighState;
            public bool bPin7LowHighState;
            public bool bPin8LowHighState;
        }
        public struct FTC_CLOSE_FINAL_STATE_PINS
        {
            public bool bTCKPinState;
            public bool bTCKPinActiveState;
            public bool bTDIPinState;
            public bool bTDIPinActiveState;
            public bool bTMSPinState;
            public bool bTMSPinActiveState;
        }

        //**************************************************************************
        // FUNCTION IMPORTS FROM FTCJTAG DLL
        //**************************************************************************
        [DllImport("ftcjtag.dll", EntryPoint = "JTAG_GetDllVersion", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        static extern uint GetDllVersion(byte[] pDllVersion, uint buufferSize);
        [DllImport("ftcjtag.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        static extern uint JTAG_GetErrorCodeString(string language, uint statusCode, byte[] pErrorMessage, uint bufferSize);
        [DllImport("ftcjtag.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        static extern uint JTAG_GetNumHiSpeedDevices(ref uint NumHiSpeedDevices);
        [DllImport("ftcjtag.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        static extern uint JTAG_GetHiSpeedDeviceNameLocIDChannel(uint deviceNameIndex, byte[] pDeviceName, uint deviceNameBufferSize, ref uint locationID, byte[] pChannel, uint channelBufferSize, ref uint hiSpeedDeviceType);
        [DllImport("ftcjtag.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        static extern uint JTAG_OpenHiSpeedDevice(string DeviceName, uint locationID, string channel, ref IntPtr pftHandle);
        [DllImport("ftcjtag.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        static extern uint JTAG_GetHiSpeedDeviceType(IntPtr ftHandle, ref uint hiSpeedDeviceType);
        [DllImport("ftcjtag.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        static extern uint JTAG_Close(IntPtr ftHandle);
        [DllImport("ftcjtag.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        static extern uint JTAG_CloseDevice(IntPtr ftHandle, ref FTC_CLOSE_FINAL_STATE_PINS pCloseFinalStatePinsData);
        [DllImport("ftcjtag.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        static extern uint JTAG_InitDevice(IntPtr ftHandle, uint clockDivisor);
        [DllImport("ftcjtag.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        static extern uint JTAG_TurnOnDivideByFiveClockingHiSpeedDevice(IntPtr ftHandle);
        [DllImport("ftcjtag.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        static extern uint JTAG_TurnOffDivideByFiveClockingHiSpeedDevice(IntPtr ftHandle);
        [DllImport("ftcjtag.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        static extern uint JTAG_TurnOnAdaptiveClockingHiSpeedDevice(IntPtr ftHandle);
        [DllImport("ftcjtag.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        static extern uint JTAG_TurnOffAdaptiveClockingHiSpeedDevice(IntPtr ftHandle);
        [DllImport("ftcjtag.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        static extern uint JTAG_SetDeviceLatencyTimer(IntPtr ftHandle, byte timerValue);
        [DllImport("ftcjtag.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        static extern uint JTAG_GetDeviceLatencyTimer(IntPtr ftHandle, ref byte timerValue);
        [DllImport("ftcjtag.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        static extern uint JTAG_GetHiSpeedDeviceClock(uint ClockDivisor, ref uint clockFrequencyHz);
        [DllImport("ftcjtag.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        static extern uint JTAG_GetClock(uint clockDivisor, ref uint clockFrequencyHz);
        [DllImport("ftcjtag.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        static extern uint JTAG_SetClock(IntPtr ftHandle, uint clockDivisor, ref uint clockFrequencyHz);
        [DllImport("ftcjtag.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        static extern uint JTAG_SetLoopback(IntPtr ftHandle, bool loopBackState);
        [DllImport("ftcjtag.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        static extern uint JTAG_SetHiSpeedDeviceGPIOs(IntPtr ftHandle, bool bControlLowInputOutputPins, ref FTC_INPUT_OUTPUT_PINS pLowInputOutputPinsData, bool bControlHighInputOutputPins, ref FTH_INPUT_OUTPUT_PINS pHighInputOutputPinsData);
        [DllImport("ftcjtag.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        static extern uint JTAG_GetHiSpeedDeviceGPIOs(IntPtr ftHandle, bool bControlLowInputOutputPins, out FTC_LOW_HIGH_PINS pLowPinsInputData, bool bControlHighInputOutputPins, out FTH_LOW_HIGH_PINS pHighPinsInputData);
        [DllImport("ftcjtag.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        static extern uint JTAG_Write(IntPtr ftHandle, bool bInstructionTestData, uint numBitsToWrite, byte[] WriteDataBuffer, uint numBytesToWrite, uint tapControllerState);
        [DllImport("ftcjtag.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        static extern uint JTAG_Read(IntPtr ftHandle, bool bInstructionTestData, uint numBitsToRead, byte[] ReadDataBuffer, ref uint numBytesReturned, uint tapControllerState);
        [DllImport("ftcjtag.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        static extern uint JTAG_WriteRead(IntPtr ftHandle, bool bInstructionTestData, uint numBitsToWriteRead, byte[] WriteDataBuffer, uint numBytesToWrite, byte[] ReadDataBuffer, ref uint numBytesReturned, uint tapControllerState);
        [DllImport("ftcjtag.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        static extern uint JTAG_GenerateClockPulses(IntPtr ftHandle, uint numClockPulses);
        [DllImport("ftcjtag.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        static extern uint JTAG_ClearCmdSequence();
        [DllImport("ftcjtag.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        static extern uint JTAG_AddWriteCmd(bool bInstructionTestData, uint numBitsToWrite, byte[] WriteDataBuffer, uint numBytesToWrite, uint tapControllerState);
        [DllImport("ftcjtag.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        static extern uint JTAG_AddReadCmd(bool bInstructionTestData, uint numBitsToRead, uint tapControllerState);
        [DllImport("ftcjtag.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        static extern uint JTAG_AddWriteReadCmd(bool bInstructionTestData, uint numBitsToWriteRead, byte[] WriteDataBuffer, uint numBytesToWrite, uint tapControllerState);
        [DllImport("ftcjtag.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        static extern uint JTAG_ExecuteCmdSequence(IntPtr ftHandle, byte[] ReadCmdSequenceDataBuffer, ref uint numBytesReturned);
        [DllImport("ftcjtag.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        static extern uint JTAG_ClearDeviceCmdSequence(IntPtr ftHandle);
        [DllImport("ftcjtag.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        static extern uint JTAG_AddDeviceWriteCmd(IntPtr ftHandle, bool bInstructionTestData, uint numBitsToWrite, byte[] WriteDataBuffer, uint numBytesToWrite, uint tapControllerState);
        [DllImport("ftcjtag.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        static extern uint JTAG_AddDeviceReadCmd(IntPtr ftHandle, bool bInstructionTestData, uint numBitsToRead, uint tapControllerState);
        [DllImport("ftcjtag.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        static extern uint JTAG_AddDeviceWriteReadCmd(IntPtr ftHandle, bool bInstructionTestData, uint numBitsToWriteRead, byte[] WriteDataBuffer, uint numBytesToWrite, uint tapControllerState);

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LowInputOutputPinsData.bPin1InputOutputState = true;    //true= Enable TCK, TMS and TDI outputs
            LowInputOutputPinsData.bPin2InputOutputState = false;
            LowInputOutputPinsData.bPin3InputOutputState = false;
            LowInputOutputPinsData.bPin4InputOutputState = false;
            LowInputOutputPinsData.bPin1LowHighState = false;       //false= Enable TCK, TMS and TDI outputs
            LowInputOutputPinsData.bPin2LowHighState = false;
            LowInputOutputPinsData.bPin3LowHighState = false;
            LowInputOutputPinsData.bPin4LowHighState = false;

            HighInputOutputPinsData.bPin1InputOutputState = false;
            HighInputOutputPinsData.bPin2InputOutputState = false;
            HighInputOutputPinsData.bPin3InputOutputState = false;
            HighInputOutputPinsData.bPin4InputOutputState = false;
            HighInputOutputPinsData.bPin5InputOutputState = false;
            HighInputOutputPinsData.bPin6InputOutputState = false;
            HighInputOutputPinsData.bPin7InputOutputState = false;
            HighInputOutputPinsData.bPin8InputOutputState = false;
            HighInputOutputPinsData.bPin1LowHighState = false;
            HighInputOutputPinsData.bPin2LowHighState = false;
            HighInputOutputPinsData.bPin3LowHighState = false;
            HighInputOutputPinsData.bPin4LowHighState = false;
            HighInputOutputPinsData.bPin5LowHighState = false;
            HighInputOutputPinsData.bPin6LowHighState = false;
            HighInputOutputPinsData.bPin7LowHighState = false;
            HighInputOutputPinsData.bPin8LowHighState = false;

            ftStatus = JTAG_GetHiSpeedDeviceNameLocIDChannel(0, byteHiSpeedDeviceName, MAX_NUM_DEVICE_NAME_CHARS, ref locationID, byteHiSpeedDeviceChannel, MAX_NUM_CHANNEL_CHARS, ref hiSpeedDeviceType);
            if (ftStatus != 0) error(Convert.ToInt32(ftStatus));
            hiSpeedChannel = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(byteHiSpeedDeviceChannel);// Trim strings to first occurrence of a null terminator character
            hiSpeedChannel = hiSpeedChannel.Substring(0, hiSpeedChannel.IndexOf("\0"));
            hiSpeedDeviceName = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(byteHiSpeedDeviceName);// Trim strings to first occurrence of a null terminator character
            hiSpeedDeviceName = hiSpeedDeviceName.Substring(0, hiSpeedDeviceName.IndexOf("\0"));// The ftHandle parameter is a pointer to a variable of type DWORD ie 32-bit unsigned integer

            ftStatus = JTAG_OpenHiSpeedDevice(hiSpeedDeviceName, locationID, hiSpeedChannel, ref ftHandle);
            if (ftStatus != 0) error(Convert.ToInt32(ftStatus));

            ftStatus = JTAG_InitDevice(ftHandle, 0);
            if (ftStatus != 0) error(Convert.ToInt32(ftStatus));

            ftStatus = JTAG_TurnOffDivideByFiveClockingHiSpeedDevice(ftHandle);
            if (ftStatus != 0) error(Convert.ToInt32(ftStatus));

            ftStatus = JTAG_SetClock(ftHandle, 6, ref clockFrequencyHz);
            if (ftStatus != 0) error(Convert.ToInt32(ftStatus));

            ftStatus = JTAG_SetHiSpeedDeviceGPIOs(ftHandle, true, ref LowInputOutputPinsData, true, ref HighInputOutputPinsData);
            if (ftStatus != 0) error(Convert.ToInt32(ftStatus));

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        void error(int e)
        {
            switch (e)
            {
                case 0: Console.WriteLine("FTC_SUCCESS 0 // FTC_OK"); break;
                case 1: Console.WriteLine("FTC_INVALID_HANDLE"); break;
                case 2: Console.WriteLine("FTC_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND"); break;
                case 3: Console.WriteLine("FTC_DEVICE_NOT_OPENED"); break;
                case 4: Console.WriteLine("FTC_IO_ERROR"); break;
                case 5: Console.WriteLine("FTC_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES"); break;
                case 20: Console.WriteLine("FTC_FAILED_TO_COMPLETE_COMMAND"); break;
                case 21: Console.WriteLine("FTC_FAILED_TO_SYNCHRONIZE_DEVICE_MPSSE"); break;
                case 22: Console.WriteLine("FTC_INVALID_DEVICE_NAME_INDEX"); break;
                case 23: Console.WriteLine("FTC_NULL_DEVICE_NAME_BUFFER_POINTER"); break;
                case 24: Console.WriteLine("FTC_DEVICE_NAME_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL"); break;
                case 25: Console.WriteLine("FTC_INVALID_DEVICE_NAME"); break;
                case 26: Console.WriteLine("FTC_INVALID_LOCATION_ID"); break;
                case 27: Console.WriteLine("FTC_DEVICE_IN_USE"); break;
                case 28: Console.WriteLine("FTC_TOO_MANY_DEVICES"); break;
                case 29: Console.WriteLine("FTC_NULL_CHANNEL_BUFFER_POINTER"); break;
                case 30: Console.WriteLine("FTC_CHANNEL_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL"); break;
                case 31: Console.WriteLine("FTC_INVALID_CHANNEL"); break;
                case 32: Console.WriteLine("FTC_INVALID_TIMER_VALUE"); break;
                case 33: Console.WriteLine("FTC_INVALID_CLOCK_DIVISOR"); break;
                case 34: Console.WriteLine("FTC_NULL_INPUT_OUTPUT_BUFFER_POINTER"); break;
                case 35: Console.WriteLine("FTC_INVALID_NUMBER_BITS"); break;
                case 36: Console.WriteLine("FTC_NULL_WRITE_DATA_BUFFER_POINTER"); break;
                case 37: Console.WriteLine("FTC_INVALID_NUMBER_BYTES"); break;
                case 38: Console.WriteLine("FTC_NUMBER_BYTES_TOO_SMALL"); break;
                case 39: Console.WriteLine("FTC_INVALID_TAP_CONTROLLER_STATE"); break;
                case 40: Console.WriteLine("FTC_NULL_READ_DATA_BUFFER_POINTER"); break;
                case 41: Console.WriteLine("FTC_COMMAND_SEQUENCE_BUFFER_FULL"); break;
                case 42: Console.WriteLine("FTC_NULL_READ_CMDS_DATA_BUFFER_POINTER"); break;
                case 43: Console.WriteLine("FTC_NO_COMMAND_SEQUENCE"); break;
                case 44: Console.WriteLine("FTC_INVALID_NUMBER_CLOCK_PULSES"); break;
                case 45: Console.WriteLine("FTC_INVALID_NUMBER_SINGLE_CLOCK_PULSES"); break;
                case 46: Console.WriteLine("FTC_INVALID_NUMBER_TIMES_EIGHT_CLOCK_PULSES"); break;
                case 47: Console.WriteLine("FTC_NULL_CLOSE_FINAL_STATE_BUFFER_POINTER"); break;
                case 48: Console.WriteLine("FTC_NULL_DLL_VERSION_BUFFER_POINTER"); break;
                case 49: Console.WriteLine("FTC_DLL_VERSION_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL"); break;
                case 50: Console.WriteLine("FTC_NULL_LANGUAGE_CODE_BUFFER_POINTER"); break;
                case 51: Console.WriteLine("FTC_NULL_ERROR_MESSAGE_BUFFER_POINTER"); break;
                case 52: Console.WriteLine("FTC_ERROR_MESSAGE_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL"); break;
                case 53: Console.WriteLine("FTC_INVALID_LANGUAGE_CODE"); break;
                case 54: Console.WriteLine("FTC_INVALID_STATUS_CODE"); break;
                default: Console.WriteLine("FTC: Unknown error occured."); break;
            }
            System.Environment.Exit(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show C++ JTAG_GetHiSpeedDeviceNameLocIDChannel signature

Comment: Hello Stecya, where do I find the signature?

Comment: do you have .h file provided with c++ dll ?

Comment: Hello Stecya, yes I have I found the lines: FTCJTAG_API
FTC_STATUS WINAPI JTAG_GetHiSpeedDeviceNameLocIDChannel(DWORD dwDeviceNameIndex, LPSTR lpDeviceNameBuffer, DWORD dwBufferSize, LPDWORD lpdwLocationID, LPSTR lpChannel, DWORD dwChannelBufferSize, LPDWORD lpdwHiSpeedDeviceType);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's been a great long while since I've last used PInvoke but I believe your issue lies, as the error message suggests, with the calling conventions of the DLL you are wrapping.

A quick look at the source for FTCJTAG.dll shows that all methods are marked WINAPI. This means they use the stdcall calling convention.

Your C# code imports these functions by telling PInvoke to use the cdecl calling convention.

If you are unfamiliar with the concept of calling conventions, wikipedia has a decent writeup [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions).

**To summarize**: your code and the DLL you are calling do not agree on how to send each other information and who is responsible for cleaning up. You need to import the functions from the dll with the stdcall convention.

Comment: Hello Bethor, thank you for the wiki link. I will try the stdcall thingy.

Answer (score 0):

The question is what you are compiling as... if you are compiling to a x86 then your 32 bit dll will work if you are compiling to "any cpu" which I think is the default... your code will run as 64 bit and you will not be able to use the 32 bit dll... switch the compile setting to x86 or use the 64 bit dll.

Comment: Hello jsobo, I think that express is not able to compile anything but x86.