# DLL Call from C# does not work in newer .Net framework(3.5 vs 4.6.1)

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I have the following code:

```
[DllImport("ftcjtag.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern uint JTAG_OpenHiSpeedDevice(string DeviceName, uint locationID, string channel, ref IntPtr pftHandle);

[DllImport("ftcjtag.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern uint JTAG_InitDevice(IntPtr ftHandle, uint clockDivisor);


IntPtr ftHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
ftStatus = JTAG_OpenHiSpeedDevice(hiSpeedDeviceName, locationId, hiSpeedChannel, ref ftHandle);
if (ftStatus != FTC_SUCCESS)
{
      throw new JTAGApiException("An error occurred while calling JTAG_OpenHiSpeedDevice for device:" + hiSpeedDeviceName + ". API Error:" + GetError(ftStatus));
}


ftStatus = JTAG_InitDevice(ftHandle, 1);

if (ftStatus != FTC_SUCCESS)
{
    throw new Exception("An error occurred during init jtag device " + HiSpeedDevice.DeviceName);
}
```

When I run it with ,Net 3.5 it works fine.

When I switch to 4.6.1, JTAG_InitDevice returns an error code saying that the handle provided is invalid. JTAG_OpenHiSpeedDevice is where I got the handle. I don't see a reason why in 3.5 the handle is valid where in 4.6.1 it's invalid.

Thx

Comment: Is the project still targeting the same *bitness*?

Comment: What do you mean by bitness? 32 vs 64? Yes it's using 64 bit in both cases. The only difference between the runs is the target .Net framework.

Comment: Your error checking is deficient. Check the return value on all API calls. Starting with the one that gave you an invalid handle.

Comment: It's not deficient, I am checking all result codes, but I did not paste that code here since it does not contribute to the question. JTAG_OpenHiSpeedDevice return 0 which is success result code in that case.

Comment: From past experience in stackoverflkow there is a trade off between the amount code you put and the attention that you'll get from the community. Putting a lot of code get people lost. I added the missing code.

Comment: You don't seem to be passing the same handle to the second function as was returned from the first function. From past experience on SO, questions with fake code aren't useful for anybody. I'm out.

Comment: The other benefit of putting together an MCVE is that you get to pare down the code to the point where it's obvious _to you_ why it's failing.

Comment: If you're using these prototypes https://github.com/jrmrjnck/ftcjtag/blob/master/FTCJTAG.cpp all methods seem to be declared as WINAPI (stdcall), so try to remove 'CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl'

Comment: Another victim of the wrong calling convention [is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5154929/unbalanced-stack-problem).  Albeit that he did it right and did not disable the debugger diagnostic.

Comment: Changing the calling convention did not help.

Comment: Nobody but you knows what's in the dll. So nobody else can be sure where the mismatch is. Good luck.